# How to know where Express.js error is coming from, error stack is no help :(

Tags: node.js, express

I keep having an error in node Express.js but I have no idea which file is calling this function as the stack gives me no info and the project is fairly large with lots of files.
This is the error stack:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param 'smart%20sync/family%20eye%20care/50%%20off%20yfed%20sign%20image.jpg'
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at decode_param (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:167:12)
    at Layer.match (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:143:15)
    at matchLayer (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:557:18)
    at next (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:15)
    at favicon (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:72:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at methodOverride (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/method-override/index.js:63:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at jsonParser (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:100:40)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:88:40)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/sites/dynasite/htdocs/_msportal/_js/_node-dist/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

now I know its coming from express, but I need to know the calling script so I can take care of it before the crash:

explodes at: `/express/lib/route/layer.js`
and function:

```
function decode_param(val) {
  if (typeof val !== 'string' || val.length === 0) {
    return val;
  }

  try {
    return decodeURIComponent(val);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof URIError) {
      err.message = 'Failed to decode param \'' + val + '\'';
      err.status = err.statusCode = 400;
    }

    throw err;
  }
}
```

How can I figure out the file that is calling the decode function if the error stack does not show it?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Well, decode_param gets called as part of the route processing pipeline, every time a route parameter is being evaluated.  If you really want to see that happening, I'd run Node in debug mode and use VS Code or Chrome debugger to step through it.

The problem with the specific string you're erroring on is that it didn't correctly encode the % sign, in the segment that would be human readable as "50% off".  "50% off" properly encodes as "50%25%20off".  So look at whatever code is generating those URLs before the request to your server-side component and fix that.

Comment: ya debugging live code is not possible... I put a special skip clause for now in express as workaround.

Comment: Are you catching the error thrown by the function? or you can just comment out the `throw err;` line instead;

Comment: @born2net I've done it before, but fine.  Assuming you can't, you should still take note of the encoding problem, as that is why the Express function is throwing an error.

Answer (score -1):

Add `try/catch` blocks around your usages of that function all over the project. This simple pattern outputs a lot of information that is not revealed otherwise:

```js
try {
  // your code
} catch (e) { console.log(e); }
```